# Не могу получить значение value из input во всплывающем окне расширеня гугл

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, popup

Когда в js я пытаюсь достать значение с помощью getElementById то мне возвращает none, так как js ищет элемент непосредственно на странице сайта, а мне нужно чтобы он находил элемент в окне popup

Manifest

```json
{
  "name": "Переключение серий на jut.su",
  "description": "Расширение автоматически переключает на следующую серию",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "16.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "16.png"
  }
}
```

Popup

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      width: 350px;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Ник</p>
  <input type="text" id="nick">
  <p>Аватарка</p>
  <input type="text" id="avatar">
  <p>Скин</p>
  <input type="text" id="skin">
  <p>Баланс</p>
  <input type="text" id="balance">
  <p>Полученные</p>
  <input type="text" id="in1">
  <p>Отправленные</p>
  <input type="text" id="from1">
  <button id="but1"></button>
  <script src="background.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Создайте popup окно в том же файле (той же странице), где расположен скрипт по обработке. Управляйте положением и видимостью popup через css и js, но результаты получить и обработать сможете.

Comment: это не то что мне нужно, я работаю с расширением и не могу достать значение из input, а оно находится во всплывающем окне расширения.